# Фильтрование результатов readdirSync

Tags: node.js

У меня стоит рекурсивный поиск в папке. Не могу понять как мне добавить регулярное выражение чтобы исключить из найденного файлы с расширением /.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const base = "/mnt/pr/01";
const imgFileRe = /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/

String.prototype.repeat = function(num){
  return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
}

function readDir(base, level){
 let files = fs.readdirSync(base, {withFileTypes: true});
  files.forEach(function(item){

state = fs.statSync(base + '/' + item);
if(state.isDirectory()){
  localBase = base + '/' + item;
  readDir(localBase, level+1);
}
else{
  let i = base + '/' + "".repeat(level*2) + item;
  fs.readFile(i, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }


   console.log(i);
    fs.writeFile(i, result, 'utf8', function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      };
    });
  });
}
});
}

 readDir(base,0);
```

Comment: Вот после `let files = readDir...` кто вам мешает проредить список как угодно?

Comment: Ну или внутри `forEach` проверять имя файла

Answer (score 0):

Решение: Пробовал использовать .filter но он работает только с массивами.
Сделал простой реплейс

```
let foto = i.replace(/^.{1,}\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/g,'');
```